# Color film developing issues

Tags: film, color, development

There's no problem with my camera, however when I try to develop color film, my negatives are consistently very dark. I am using CineStill and following the instructions exactly, to include push times and temperature. What could be the issue and how can I correct it.
Thanks

Comment: If you are 100% sure that there is no problem with your camera and you follow the developer instructions correctly (I would not be so sure in your case), you must be metering the light incorrectly and over-exposing the film.

Comment: My first shot at this would be to give one the film to some pro lab, and see if they get a correct negative from it just to rule out camera problems. Or make it simpler and try with B&W film.